# Cannot explicitly convert type ‘System.collections.ArrayList’ to mywebservicecall.ServiceReference1.groupitems

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0, arraylist, json.net

I’m trying to pass array list like below but getting the above errors. The code works fine by just passing myitem but I need to be able to pass multiple as well.

This is my code:

```
var deserializedm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mulitipay>>(mpay.ToString());

int num = 0;
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

foreach (Mulitipay m in deserializedm)
{
    num++;
    string f = m.Fund;
    string a = m.Amount;
    int am = System.Convert.ToInt32(a);
    string g = m.Gl;
    string d = m.Details;


    var itd = new ServiceReference1.glItemDetails();
    itd.fundCode = f;
    itd.additionalReference = reference;


    var its = new ServiceReference1.Data();
    its.description = d;
    its.reference = g;
    its.amountInMinorUnits = am;

    var myitem = new ServiceReference1.sampleGroupItem();
    myitem.lgItemDetails = itd;
    myitem.itemSummary = its;
    myitem.lineId = "tetetetet1232323";
    list.Add(myitem);
}

var alllist = list;

simpleivr.sale = new ServiceReference1.samplesale ();
simpleivr.sale.saleSummary = new ServiceReference1.Data();
simpleivr.sale.saleSummary.description = "stuff1";
simpleivr.sale.saleSummary.reference = "000303";
simpleivr.sale.saleSummary.amountInMinorUnits = 400;
simpleivr.sale.items = new ServiceReference1.SampleGroupItem [] { alllist};
```

Webservice(Sample of the webservice not the full thing)

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=2)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Groupitem" IsNullable=false)]
public SampleGroupItem[] GroupItems{
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Groupitems");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array list is something that is similar to `List<Object>`. You are assigning it to an array of type `SampleGroupItem`. You just need to change the `ArrayList` to `List<SampleGroupItem>` and then call the method `.ToArray()`
So your code will become

```
  var deserializedm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mulitipay>>(mpay.ToString());
        int num = 0;
        List<ServiceReference1.SampleGroupItem> list = new List<ServiceReference1.SampleGroupItem>();

        foreach (Mulitipay m in deserializedm)
        {
            num++;
            string f = m.Fund;
            string a = m.Amount;
            int am = System.Convert.ToInt32(a);
            string g = m.Gl;
            string d = m.Details;


            var itd = new ServiceReference1.glItemDetails();
            itd.fundCode = f;
            itd.additionalReference = reference;


            var its = new ServiceReference1.Data();
            its.description = d;
            its.reference = g;
            its.amountInMinorUnits = am;

            var myitem = new ServiceReference1.sampleGroupItem();
            myitem.lgItemDetails = itd;
            myitem.itemSummary = its;
            myitem.lineId = "tetetetet1232323";
            list.Add(myitem);
        }

        simpleivr.sale = new ServiceReference1.samplesale ();
        simpleivr.sale.saleSummary = new ServiceReference1.Data();
        simpleivr.sale.saleSummary.description = "stuff1";
        simpleivr.sale.saleSummary.reference = "000303";
        simpleivr.sale.saleSummary.amountInMinorUnits = 400;
        simpleivr.sale.items = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Cheers @Mahmoud, I will try this and let you know

Comment: Glad I helped, you should close the question now.

Comment: I dont have enough points to vote your answer. I might have to keep this question open maybe it might be useful to others if you think otherwise do let me know and I will close it.

Comment: When you close the question it doesn't go away, when you close the question by choosing the answer that solved your problem it will help other figure out the correct solution by searching in the site and finding your question which is solved [ an answer has been chosen ]